# Swift: Can't set UIButton image programmatically with error: 'NSString' not a subtype of 'UIImage'

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimage, ios8, ios8-extension

I am trying to set a button image programmatically, and no one seems to have problems with this but me.

My Code:

```
func moreOptionsKeyMap(){
    for x in self.mainView.subviews as [UIButton]
    {
        let image = UIImage(named: "\(numberImages[0])") as UIImage
        if x.tag == 0 {
            x.setImage(UIImage (named: image), forState: .Normal)
        }

    }
}
```

I tried directly plugging in the name of the image (This is the line throwing the error)

```
x.setImage(UIImage (named: "1Key.png"), forState: .Normal)
```

but I keep getting the same error.

I found an answer on Stackoverflow that said the solution is:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "name") as UIImage
let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
```

and everyone says that works fine, so I can't imagine what is wrong with mine.

I'm making a keyboard, so I have buttons set up in Interface Builder, and then in my viewDidLoad

```
for v in self.mainView.subviews as [UIButton]
    {
        v.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }
```

then in the buttonPressed method I have a switch that calls moreOptionsKeyMap()

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Question is pretty obvious....not sure how you missed it. How do I do this without an error? Isn't that the goal of everyone who programs?

Comment: There needs to be a clear problem statement, your question does not have one.

Comment: You're right, I edited it. It now says which line throws the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a first glance I would say that here:

```
x.setImage(UIImage (named: image), forState: .Normal)
```

you are passing `image`, which is a `UIImage`, whereas a string is expected.

I think you have to turn this line:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "\(numberImages[0])") as UIImage
```

into:

```
let image = "\(numberImages[0])"
```

So this is how your method should look like:

```
func moreOptionsKeyMap() {
    for x in self.mainView.subviews as [UIButton]
    {
        let image = "\(numberImages[0])"
        if x.tag == 0 {
            x.setImage(UIImage (named: image), forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? a gist is ok. I tested my modifications on a playground and it compiles

Comment: That's pretty much all of the related code... check what I added, see if it's enough

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer adding your method with my modifications. Please try it, it's compiling here, and with your original code I receive the same error. Also the error itself indicates that the problem is about using a `UIImage` where `NSString` is expected.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how my code looks, and I get the same error... That's why I tried removing the possibility that numberImages had the wrong string or something and just directly typed a string into the code:     x.setImage(UIImage (named: "1Key.png"), forState: .Normal) but I get the same error.

Comment: Wow, the problem was Xcode. I cleaned the project and it compiled fine. Thanks for the help!! Appreciate it.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked :) the swift compiler often provides unmeaningful error messages, but in this case it really seemed a nonsense

Comment: I thought so too! I just tested it with the new code and compiled it, ran it, and my app crashed. Time to tackle the next problem..... :P